# Problem Showing Markers created by JSON request in Flutter

Tags: dictionary, dart, flutter, maps

I'm trying to create markers with a JSON, response, the JSON y working correctly, and the map is also working, but the markers are not showed in the map.

I know something is wrong with the code, but I can't find the solution, or something similar to fix it `

```
 var farmcias = Farmacia.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
    for (var result in farmcias.result.toList()) {
      titulo = result?.title;
      calle = result?.calle;
      lat = result?.geometry.coordinates[0];
      long = result?.geometry.coordinates[1];

      markers.add( Marker(
    width: 80.0,
    height: 80.0,
    point: new LatLng(lat, long),
    builder: (ctx) =>
     Container(
      child:  FlutterLogo(colors: Colors.purple),
    ),
  ));
  return markers;
}
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FetchJSON();
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Padding(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Padding(
              padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 18.0, bottom: 18.0),
            ),
            new Flexible(
              child: new FlutterMap(
                options: new MapOptions(
                  center: new LatLng(41.652833, -0.889830),
                  zoom: 12.0,
                ),
                layers: [
                  new TileLayerOptions(
                      urlTemplate:
                      "https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                      subdomains: ['a', 'b', 'c']),
                  new MarkerLayerOptions(markers: markers)
                ],`
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: You are probably building your UI without the waiting FetchJSON to complete. Try using await.

Comment: I have the await in the request, to get the respones.  'FetchJSON() async {
    var response = await http.get('